# Spark filter functionality is giving error

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is the sample raw data

```
tweet_id,airline_sentiment,airline_sentiment_confidence,negativereason,negativereason_confidence,airline,airline_sentiment_gold,name,negativereason_gold,retweet_count,text,tweet_coord,tweet_created,tweet_location,user_timezone
570306133677760513,neutral,1.0,,,Virgin America,,cairdin,,0,@VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said.,,2015-02-24 11:35:52 -0800,,Eastern Time (US & Canada)
```

Below is my program

```
val data = sc.textFile("/user/inputs/Tweets.csv")
val map_data = data.map(x=> x.split(","))
val filterdata  = map_data.filter(x=> x(5) == "Virgin America").count()
```

it gives the exception as below :

```
[Stage 0:>                                                                                                                                                                        (0 + 2) / 2]
20/02/21 21:50:41 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, ip-10-0-1-10.ec2.internal, executor 1): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5                       
        at $line27.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:31)                                                                                               
        at $line27.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:31)
```

Comment: data is not splittable in your code and you are trying to access index 5 which is the cause see my code with full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your data is not splittable some how thats the reason for getting array index out of bound see below code.... which will replicate your version in option 1

I refined it with spark csv api which may be useful for you.

```
    package examples

    import org.apache.log4j.Level

    object CSVTest extends App {
      import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
      val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
      val logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org")
      logger.setLevel(Level.WARN)
      import spark.implicits._
      import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
      val csvData: Dataset[String] = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(
        """
          |tweet_id,airline_sentiment,airline_sentiment_confidence,negativereason,negativereason_confidence,airline,airline_sentiment_gold,name,negativereason_gold,retweet_count,text,tweet_coord,tweet_created,tweet_location,user_timezone
          |570306133677760513,neutral,1.0,,,Virgin America,,cairdin,,0,@VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said.,,2015-02-24 11:35:52 -0800,,Eastern Time (US & Canada)
        """.stripMargin.lines.toList).toDS()


      println("option 2 : spark csv version ")
      val frame = spark.read.option("header", true).option("inferSchema",true).csv(csvData)
      frame.show()
      frame.printSchema()
     println( frame.filter($"airline" === "Virgin America").count())

     println("option 1: your version which is not splittable thats the reason getting arrayindex out of bound ")
      val filterdata = csvData.map(x=> x.split(","))
      filterdata.foreach(x => println(x.mkString))
    //    filterdata.show(false)
    //    filterdata.filter {x=> {
    //      println(x)
    //      x(5) == "Virgin America"
    //    }
    //    }
    //  .count()


    }
```

Result :

```
option 2 : spark csv version 
+------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|          tweet_id|airline_sentiment|airline_sentiment_confidence|negativereason|negativereason_confidence|       airline|airline_sentiment_gold|   name|negativereason_gold|retweet_count|                text|tweet_coord|       tweet_created|tweet_location|       user_timezone|
+------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+
|570306133677760513|          neutral|                         1.0|          null|                     null|Virgin America|                  null|cairdin|               null|            0|@VirginAmerica Wh...|       null|2015-02-24 11:35:...|          null|Eastern Time (US ...|
+------------------+-----------------+----------------------------+--------------+-------------------------+--------------+----------------------+-------+-------------------+-------------+--------------------+-----------+--------------------+--------------+--------------------+

root
 |-- tweet_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- airline_sentiment: string (nullable = true)
 |-- airline_sentiment_confidence: double (nullable = true)
 |-- negativereason: string (nullable = true)
 |-- negativereason_confidence: string (nullable = true)
 |-- airline: string (nullable = true)
 |-- airline_sentiment_gold: string (nullable = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- negativereason_gold: string (nullable = true)
 |-- retweet_count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- text: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tweet_coord: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tweet_created: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tweet_location: string (nullable = true)
 |-- user_timezone: string (nullable = true)

1
option 1: your version which is not splittable thats the reason getting arrayindex out of bound 
tweet_idairline_sentimentairline_sentiment_confidencenegativereasonnegativereason_confidenceairlineairline_sentiment_goldnamenegativereason_goldretweet_counttexttweet_coordtweet_createdtweet_locationuser_timezone
570306133677760513neutral1.0Virgin Americacairdin0@VirginAmerica What @dhepburn said.2015-02-24 11:35:52 -0800Eastern Time (US & Canada)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Your option 1 is printing the split array, not the read lines of the file. Use mkString

Comment: I used your approach as below ,I converted the date into dataframe and then registered as temp table and then analyse the data

Comment: val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Scala Twitter Data analysis Example").setMaster("local[1]") 
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
        val data = sc.textFile("C:\\Sankhadeep\\Study\\data\\twitter-airline-sentiment\\Tweets.csv", 2)
        
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
        val df = spark.read.option("header", "true").option("inferSchema",true).csv("C:\\Sankhadeep\\Study\\data\\twitter-airline-sentiment\\Tweets.csv").toDF()
        df.show()
     df.printSchema()
df.registerTempTable("twitter_data")

Comment: But my question is that why I can't use the array here with split function, why I am getting this arrayindexbound exception .The data seems to be fine only

Comment: With plain scala code can you split... With out using spark you can understand

Comment: I want to understand why the data is not splitable , even when I tried with different csv dataset , I got the same error .

Comment: I cant see null data in the original post can you show me where is null data as mentioned in your answer ?

Comment: Hi Ram , can you please help me for the below issue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515843/spark-scala-error-error-main-method-not-found-in-class

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution , it is some null data on my dataset which was causing the arrayindexoutofboundexception.I changed the function as below :

I used array.length function to filter out those rows where we have the null data

### Sample Data

DBN,School Name,Number of Test Takers,Critical Reading Mean,Mathematics Mean,Writing Mean
01M292,Henry Street School for International Studies ,31,391,425,385
01M448,University Neighborhood High School ,60,394,419,387
01M450,East Side Community High School ,69,418,431,402
01M458,SATELLITE ACADEMY FORSYTH ST ,26,385,370,378
01M509,CMSP HIGH SCHOOL ,,,,

'''

```
     val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Scala School Data analysis Example").setMaster("local[1]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf) 
    val data = sc.textFile("C:\\Sankhadeep\\Study\\data\\SAT_School_Level_Results.csv", 2)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("sample").master("local").getOrCreate()
    val map_data = data.map(x=> x.split(","))
    //val map_data1 = map_data.map(x=> handleNull(x))
    val sample = map_data.filter(x=> (x.length > 4)).filter(x=> (x(4) != "Mathematics Mean")).filter(x=> (x(4).toInt > 500  ))
    '''
```