# Spark Scala Error - Error: Main method not found in class

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I was trying to the below simple spark program and I am getting the below error .Please help

```
package com.spark.DataAnalysis

import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object TwitterData {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("Start")
    System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir","C://Sankha//Study//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2//spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7")
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Scala WordCount Example").setMaster("local[1]")
        val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("CsvExample").master("local").getOrCreate()
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val csvData = sc.textFile("C:\\Sankha\\Study\\data\\twitter-airline-sentiment\\Tweets.csv",3)
        val map_data = csvData.map(x=> x.split(",")).filter(x=> (x.length  < 13)).filter(x=> x(5) == "Virgin America")
        println(map_data.count())

  }
}
```

Getting the exception as below ,I am sure it is not because of the code , but for some other issue:

```
Error: Main method not found in class com.spark.DataAnalysis.TwitterData, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: How are you building/packaging and running this program?

Comment: I am just doing a clean and build project from Scala Eclipse IDE

Comment: Please let me know whether I should follow a different approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was present with pom.xml,I changed that and it got solved